# How to save a live video capture where CIFilter is applied, in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, video-processing

I have an imageView, beneath that a 'record' button. When app starts, video capture starts (just capture, no saving anywhere) using AVCaptureSession object. Tap the **record** button, recording (actual saving) should start, tap the same again and the same will stop.

**Plain video capturing starts using below code.**

```
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self as AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer delegate"))
    captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
    captureSession.startRunning()
```

**Below is the record button action**

```
@IBAction func recordFunc() {

    if(startRecording) {
       //Initialise the saving video tools

       let fileUrl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("newMovie1.mp4") 
       //docsurl has the document directory path
       videoWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: fileUrl, fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie)

       let outputSettings: [String : Any] = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoWidthKey : NSNumber(value: Float(outputSize.width)), AVVideoHeightKey : NSNumber(value: Float(outputSize.height))]

       writerInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: outputSettings)
       writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true     
       videoWriter.add(writerInput)

       //Now, the killer line for saving the video
       adapter = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: writerInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: nil)  

       videoWriter.startWriting()
       videoWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: kCMTimeZero)
    }
    else {
       //Video saving is complete !!

       self.writerInput.markAsFinished()
       self.videoWriter.finishWriting { () -> Void in
            print("FINISHED.")
       }
    }
}
```

In the above code, adapter - *AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor* type, has some special role in saving video.

**Now the main the decisive code block, causing pain is here:**
 The *AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate's*  **captureOutput()** method

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!){

        connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.rawValue)!

        let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        cameraImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)

        let comicEffect = CIFilter(name: "CIComicEffect")!  // The great 'CIFilter'

        //Below 2 lines calls a function which detects a face and attaches two cartoon eye images to the user's eye positions.
        let leftEyeImage = eyeImage(cameraImage: cameraImage!, backgroundImage: cameraImage!, leftEye: true)
        let rightEyeImage = eyeImage(cameraImage: cameraImage!, backgroundImage: leftEyeImage, leftEye: false)

        comicEffect.setValue(rightEyeImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        let outputImage = comicEffect.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
        let filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage: outputImage) 

        //Feed the imageView, the UIImage thing 'filteredImage'
        DispatchQueue.main.async(){
            self.imgViewActual.image = filteredImage 
        }

        //The MAIN line, only responsible for saving is below.  
        self.adapter.append(somePixelBuffr , withPresentationTime: someTime)
    }
```

So, **somePixelBuffr = ???** and **someTime = ???**

Or is there anything I should add here or modify here. Please suggest.

**Constraints:** Solution in Swift >=3.0, Video capturing should not lag.